# Comparator for Java classes?

Tags: java

I want to compare two Java classes.

```
class ClassComparator implements Comparator<Class> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Class arg0, Class arg1) {
        return ....;
    }
}
```

I could just compare class names, but I want parent classes be "smaller" than classes derived from them. And I want this *less-than* relation to be transitive and work for any two classes. (To be honest, in my real problem one class will always be a superclass of another, but I want some general-case code because in theory this can change.)

**Maybe this is already done and someone can share a code snippet?**

What comes to my mind is: if none of the classes is derived from another, find their two superclasses derived from the common ancestor, and compare their names. (Hmmm, it can even support interfaces, if any object class is greater than any interface.)

Comment: Generally comparator is used not to compare the class objects themselves but some value contained within the class as a field or am I misunderstanding your question.

Comment: And what if there is no parent/child relationship between the classes? What should the comparator return then?

Comment: I don't think what you have described constitutes a well-defined order.

Comment: This does seem more like you want a "flattened tree" of sorts, if so then perhaps you could consider building such a tree and walking it to form your ordered list

Comment: @AndyTurner that's the point: I want to define a total ordering that extends the _child<parent_ partial order.

Answer (score 7):

You can also compare classes that are not in one hierarchy by how deep are they and far away from Object class.

```
    class ClassComparator implements Comparator<Class> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Class arg0, Class arg1) {
        boolean arg0assignable = arg0.isAssignableFrom(arg1);
        boolean arg1assignable = arg1.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
        if (arg0assignable == arg1assignable && arg0assignable) {
            return 0;
        } else if (arg0assignable) {
            return -1;
        } else if (arg1assignable){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return compareByDistanceToObject(arg0, arg1);
        }
    }

    private int compareByDistanceToObject(Class arg0, Class arg1) {
        int distanceToObject0 = getDistance(arg0);
        int distanceToObject1 = getDistance(arg1);
        if (distanceToObject0 == distanceToObject1) {
            return 0;
        } else if (distanceToObject0 < distanceToObject1) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    private int getDistance(Class clazz) {
        if (clazz == Object.class) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + getDistance(clazz.getSuperclass());
    }
```

Comment: this is good, and it could be piped into a second comparator using the class name by something like `.thenComparing((a,b)->a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()))`

Comment: This wouldn't produce a consistent ordering. You can have `compare(X,A)=0` and `compare(Y,A)=0` but `compare(X,Y)<0`.

Comment: @khelwood can you provide an example of class hierarchy for it ?

Comment: Yes. Suppose `Y` inherits from `X`, and `A` is unrelated.

Comment: @khelwood i wrote, that it works only for classes in one hierarchy. compare have only 3 defined relations - >, <, =. And if we want to compare classes from different hierarchies, we need to defined one more relation that is impossible. Or defined some consistent ordering for this stuff.

Comment: @OrestSavchak That's why I think the appropriate answer to the OP's question is that the order being described is not well-defined.

Comment: @khelwood i updated an answer, so now it will at least have defined order and keep consistency.

Comment: @OrestSavchak Good idea.

Comment: Is there not one hierarchy for *all* non-primitive datatypes (starting with `Object`), a la [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41746280/1391325)?

Comment: @errantlinguist sorry, i didn't get your question, could you explain ? all classes are inherited from Object class.

Comment: @OrestSavchak I lost track of where the comments fit in with your edits; It looks like somewhere/at some time you didn't incorporate that fact into your answer... but does your answer not do redundant searches, anyway?-- the information you get from `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)` can be derived from the result of your `compareByDistanceToObject(..)` method.

Comment: @errantlinguist it can be, correct, but it was edited, you are right, and it is more optimal to check firstly is classes in one hierarchy. also you can check for a distance to first generic parent, not object, but it requires much more code

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints do not yield an ordered set.

```
class C {}
class B {}
class A extends C {}
```

Then you have:

- A < B
- B < C
- C < A

**EDIT:** Since [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) imposes a total ordering, there is no solution to your question.

**EDIT 2:** However, if there is no solution within your constraints, you can change them. If your objective is to define a total order among classes, so that a superclass is always *less-than* a subclass (ignoring interfaces) (i.e. we don't require to compare class names anymore), you can:

1. make a list of the (linear) hierarchy for each class
2. compare the resulting lists

*I just realized that comparing class names was not a requirement in your question.*

Let's take an example:

```
class C {}
class B {}
class A extends C {}
class D extends A {}
```

List the hierarchy of each class:

- C → (C)
- B → (B)
- A → (C, A)
- D → (C, A, D)

Then, you get a total order:

- B → (B)
- C → (C)
- A → (C, A)
- D → (C, A, D)

Comment: Your answer makes a valid point; however, it doesn't answer OP's question. Maybe it should be a comment instead.

Comment: "[Comparator] imposes a total ordering" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html → There is no solution to the question.

Comment: @rom1v I think you're absolutely right about this. A partially defined order cannot be used as a total order.

Comment: OP's question is about comparing classes (based on their hierarchy relationship and their name), not about specifically implementing `Comparator<Class>`. If it can't or, rather, shouldn't be done with a `Comparator`, then propose a different solution. An answer that just says "you can't do it with a `Comparator`" has very little value.

Comment: "And I want this less-than relation to be transitive and work for any two classes." There is no solution. Comparator or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to just do:

```
new Comparator<Class>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Class o1, Class o2) {
            if (o1 == o2)
                return 0;
            if (o1.isAssignableFrom(o2))
                return -1;
            if (o2.isAssignableFrom(o1))
                return 1;
            return o1.getSimpleName().compareTo(o2.getSimpleName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: be careful to address the special case of o1==o2. oh wait, you do, in a way. But I'd check getName(), not getSimpleName()

Comment: Good spot - fixed in the answer

Comment: That will not work: in the hierarchy A<Z<B, A<T we will have Z>T (alphabetically), T>B (alphabetically), and B>Z (as a subclass).

Answer (score 1):

So, we want to define a total order on classes such that any parent class/interface is "smaller" than any derived class/interface.

The solution is:

1. Any interface class is smaller than any object class.
2. to compare two interfaces, we compare the number of their superinterfaces. If they are equal, we compare their names.
3. to compare two object classes, we compare the number their of superclasses.  If they are equal, we compare their names.

Why this is correct. A derived class always have more ancestors than any of its its superclasses. So if we compare the number of ancestors, we guarantee that superclasses go before their descendants. And as to the ordering within the group of classes that have N parents, any ordering will do, alphabetic ordering is ok.

```
class ClassComparator implements Comparator<Class<?>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Class<?> first, Class<?> second) {
        int areInterfaces = first.isInterface() ? 1 : 0;
        areInterfaces += second.isInterface() ? 2 : 0;
        switch (areInterfaces) {
        case 1 + 2:
            return compareNumbersThenNames(getInterfaceCount(first), getInterfaceCount(second), first, second);
        case 0 + 2:
            return -1;
        case 1 + 0:
            return 1;
        case 0 + 0:
        default:
            return compareNumbersThenNames(getAncestorCount(first), getAncestorCount(second), first, second);
        }
    }
    private int compareNumbersThenNames(int f, int s, Class<?> first, Class<?> second) {
        if (f-s != 0) {
            return f-s;
        } else {
            return compareByName(first, second);
        }
    }
    private int getAncestorCount(Class<?> objectClass) {
        int res=0;
        for (Class<?> i = objectClass; i != null ; i = i.getSuperclass()) {
            res++;
        }
        return res;
    }
    private int getInterfaceCount(Class<?> interfaceClass) {
        Set<Class<?>> superInterfaces = new HashSet<>();
        addSuperinterfaces(superInterfaces, interfaceClass);
        return superInterfaces.size();
    }
    private void addSuperinterfaces(Set<Class<?>>set, Class<?>interfaceClass) {
        for (Class<?> s : interfaceClass.getInterfaces()) {
            if (!set.contains(s)) {
                set.add(s);
                addSuperinterfaces(set, s);
            }
        }
    }
    private int compareByName(Class<?> a, Class<?> b) {
        int res = a.getSimpleName().compareTo(b.getSimpleName());
        if (res != 0) { return res; }
        res = a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
        // we do not support different class loaders
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to exclude duplicate super interfaces from the total count? The numbers will differ, but still usable.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to post ([Orest Savchak posted a very similar-but-not-quite-the-same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41745297/1391325) a bit before), but you can find the closest common ancestor and then calculate each class' distance to this object. *All* classes (except for classes for primitives) have a common ancestor (at the very worst, the [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class), and we can use this information in order to ensure there is some ordering: At the worst, you can simply compare the two classes on their "depth" in their respective inheritance hierarchies rooted from `Object`.

Additionally, if while navigating the class hierarchy one compared class is found, the other class is then proven to be a child and thus is "greater" than the other one:

```
public final class InheritanceDepthComparator<T> implements Comparator<Class<? extends T>> {

    private static class B {};
    private static class C {};
    private static class A extends C {};

    private static <SUP, SUB extends SUP> int calculateInheritanceDistance(final Class<? extends SUB> o1,
            final Class<? extends SUP> o2) {
        int result = 0;
        Class<?> o1Parent = o1;
        do {
            o1Parent = o1Parent.getSuperclass();
            result++;
        } while (!Objects.equals(o1Parent, o2));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(final Class<? extends T> o1, final Class<? extends T> o2) {
        int result = 0;
        if (!o1.equals(o2)) {
            // Walk up the inheritance hierarchy
            int o1Depth = -1;
            Class<?> o1Parent = o1;
            do {
                o1Parent = o1Parent.getSuperclass();
                o1Depth++;
                if (o1Parent.equals(o2)) {
                    // The first compared object is a child of the second and
                    // therefore "greater" than it
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                } else if (o1Parent.isAssignableFrom(o2)) {
                    // Found the common ancestor class; At least by reaching
                    // "Object", this should always be executed anyway
                    // TODO: Check performance and see if manually going up the tree for o2 within this while loop itself is not faster
                    final int o2Depth = calculateInheritanceDistance(o2, o1Parent);
                    result = Integer.compare(o1Depth, o2Depth);
                    break;
                }
            } while (o1Parent != null);

        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final InheritanceDepthComparator<Object> cComp = new InheritanceDepthComparator<>();
        System.out.println("Parent compared to child: " + cComp.compare(C.class, A.class));
        System.out.println("Child compared to parent: " + cComp.compare(A.class, C.class));
        System.out.println("C (child) Compared to Object (parent): " + cComp.compare(A.class, Object.class));
        System.out.println("Sibling classes:" + cComp.compare(A.class, B.class));
    }
}
```

You can then use this `Comparator` in a chain in order to handle sibling classes:

```
final Comparator<Class<?>> cmp = new InheritanceDepthComparator<>().thenComparing(Class::getName);
```